# Convention for naming tables with lists of possible values

Tags: sql, database, naming-conventions

How do you usually call tables to store lists of possible values for fields in other tables. What prefix/suffix would you use?
For example:

```
contract_type (
  contract_type_id,
  contract_type_name,
  region_id,
  vehicle_type_id
)
region (
  region_id,
  region_name
)
vehicle_type (
  vehicle_type_id,
  vehicle_type_name
)
```

I want to distinguish such tables with possible values from tables with main entities.

I could add them a suffix *_catalog: contract_type_catalog, region_catalog, vehicle_type_catalog.

Or *_directory, or *_dictionary? Or there are better commonly used names for such tables?

Answer (score 0):

There is no convention. You can call them whatever you want - that makes sense to you and will make sense to anyone else looking at the tables